# How to pass PHP url variables to AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

How could I pass PHP URL variables to AJAX so I can get the page content load in the same page ??   Here is an example of what I am trying to to do .. I am trying for example to get the "profile.php?id= to AJAX so that page content be be loaded .. However , I first started using a loop .. I dont know if that's the right way to go about it ..

Below is the code

```
<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>


<?php
require('../madscore/database/connect.php');
database_connect();
$query = "select * from Entertainers";
$result = $connection->query($query);
$row_count =$result->num_rows;

for($i = 1; $i <= $row_count; $i++)
  {
   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    //echo $i. "<br />";
   // echo $row['Name']."<br />";
   // echo $row['Profession']."<br />";
   // echo $row['Score']."<br />";

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","profile.php?id="<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>, true");
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>




<?php  echo "<a href='/profile.php?id=".$row['ID']."' onclick='loadXMLDoc()'><img src ='../".$row['Picture']."' width='100' height='100' /> </a>"; } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user1787184 we are not here to just give you the solution of your question, we need something in return

Comment: @coders how can I accept answers .. new to this forum

Comment: can you see tick mark with every answer..??? just click there. it will become green color tick, which means you have accepted that answer. You can even move your mouse, hint will be shown to you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send javascript variable to php using ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727227/how-to-send-javascript-variable-to-php-using-ajax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this --

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","profile.php?id="<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>, true");
```

To this --

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","profile.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>", true);
```

EDIT as per comments -
Try this-

```
myid = <?php echo $row['ID'] ?>; 

//myid = "<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>";  //Or this if its a string type 


xmlhttp.open("GET","profile.php?id="+myid, true);
```

After such a long chat --

```
<?php  echo "<a href='/profile.php?id=".$row['ID']."' onclick='loadXMLDoc(".$row['ID'].")'><img src ='../".$row['Picture']."' width='100' height='100' /> </a>"; } ?>
```

Pass `$row['ID']` to your loadXMLDoc() method.

Final Code ---

```
<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>


<?php
require('../madscore/database/connect.php');
database_connect();
$query = "select * from Entertainers";
$result = $connection->query($query);
$row_count =$result->num_rows;

for($i = 1; $i <= $row_count; $i++)
  {
   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();      
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc( myid )
{
var xmlhttp;
var myloveid = id;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","profile.php?id="+myloveid, true");
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>




<?php  echo "<a href='/profile.php?id=".$row['ID']."' onclick='loadXMLDoc(".$row['ID'].")'><img src ='../".$row['Picture']."' width='100' height='100' /> </a>"; } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user1787184 profile.php path is correct?? or try with this /profile.php?id=23 (Your id) try with a dummy id first and let me know then

Comment: it is correct .. I tried with a numeric id and it returns the profile .. I am wondering how to pass the php variable containing the ID so it can fetch the profile .. your help would be so much appreciated

Comment: The idea is supposed to be generated from the link I click  on with the pictures .. so shouldn't myid have the dollar sign of php ?

Comment: @user1787184 its a JS variable and i m picturing you to show using php variable value in JS

Comment: It's not working :(  when I click on  echo "<a href='/profile.php?id=".$row['ID']."' onclick='loadXMLDoc()'><img src ='../".$row['Picture']."' width='100' height='100' /> </a>";}  .. I'd like the ID passed to this link be sent to the AJAX .. how can I do it ?

Comment: @user1787184 got it your quotes are conflicting..do i provide u the solution or you will do it on your own..check ' at img

Comment: I am not rejecting your help bro .. I appreciate it instead ... so the images are getting displayed fine from the loop , it's just that the AJAX doesn't return the image .. so about the quotes .. they should be single quotes in the AJAX you mean ?

Comment: @let me give u an answer..give me a min or two :)

Comment: @user1787184 just try this and let me know.. try using firebug :)    <?php
echo "<a href='/profile.php?id='".
   $row['ID'].
   " onclick='loadXMLDoc()'>".
   "<img src ='../".$row['Picture']."' width='100' height='100' /> </a>";
   }

Comment: @user1787184 is it on live site..if its not a big concern can i have a link plz to look what exactly is missing (working on many fronts this time..let me look it further )

Comment: it's offline unfortunately :(

Comment: @user1787184 ok np..all good can u plz tell me what url is actually been created ?? view source or use firebug..try F12 in Google chrome

Comment: ok .. They are actually image hyperlinks , so when you click on an image , it redirects you to profile.php?id=2 example of that image depending on what id was passed through the url and that is generated by the loop above.

Comment: @swapneshThe links are ok ,... it's just that I don't know how to pass the $row['ID'] of the links to AJAX so that it can load the right content .. u know what I mean ?

Comment: @user1787184 lol..i just looked at your code thoroughly and got ur problem..giving u the fine solution

Comment: THANK YOU .. if you could help me with that .. THAT'D BE GREAT man !!! I'm still learning.

Comment: @user1787184 have you checked my edit code in the answer section..sorry was at lunch

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","profile.php?id="<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>, true");
```

with this

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","profile.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>, true");
```

The `;` is very important.
If you dont write it then it will not echo the value.